# Snapshot returns Null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-html

I have this custom Data Model named `"ServiceModel"` as below:

```
class ServiceModel {
  int status;
  String message;
  List<dynamic> errors;
  Data data;

  ServiceModel({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.errors,
    required this.data,
  });

  factory ServiceModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ServiceModel(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
        errors: List<dynamic>.from(json["errors"].map((x) => x)),
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
        "errors": List<dynamic>.from(errors.map((x) => x)),
        "data": data.toJson(),
      };
}

class Data {
  Data({
    required this.serviceInfo,
    required this.payInfo,
  });

  ServiceIfo serviceInfo;
  PayInfo payInfo;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        serviceInfo: ServiceIfo.fromJson(json["serviceIfo"]),
        payInfo: PayInfo.fromJson(json["payInfo"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "serviceInfo": serviceInfo.toJson(),
        "payInfo": payInfo.toJson(),
      };
}
```

And I want to get a response from my API with this function:

```
  Future<ServiceModel> getServiceDetail() async {
    var url = "${MyStrings.baseUrl}api/providers/profile/ServiceAPI";
    var _pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var header = {
      'token': _pref.getString('token'),
    };
    var response = await http.get(url + '?serviceId=59', headers: header);
    print(response.body);
    var model = ServiceModel.fromJson((json.decode(response.body)));
    print("Model is : $model");
    return model;
  }
```

And Display it with a `FutureBuilder` as below:

```
FutureBuilder<ServiceModel>(
            future: _service.getServiceDetail(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                print('snapshot: ${snapshot.data}');
                return Center(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                    child: (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                        ? Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Container(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                color: parseColor("F8A387"),
                              ),
                            ))
                        : DetailedServicePager(data: snapshot.data!));
              }
            },
          )
```

Everything seems smooth here but it doesn't work!! Snapshot returns null and the loading indicator is displayed.

In fact It seems everything past the **model** line:

`var model = ServiceModel.fromJson((json.decode(response.body)));`

Doesn't work!!

I have Proved it by placing `print("Model is : $model");` between `model definition` and `return model`

I added a sample of my postman response by request:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Successful",
    "errors": [],
    "data": {
        "serviceIfo": {
            "serviceId": 59,
            "customerId": 3,
            "providerId": 4,
            "parentTitle": [],
            "title": "Cleaning",
            "price": 90000.0,
            "date": "2022/1/1",
            "time": "00:45",
            "address": "string",
            "specialDescription": [
                {
                    "question": "test",
                    "featureType": 0,
                    "choice": "test",
                    "answer": "test"
                }
            ],
            "description": "string",
            "lat": 0.0,
            "lng": 0.0,
            "customerFullName": "FirstName LastName",
            "custoemrPhoneNumber": "",
            "serviceStatus": "Abort Search",
            "endTime": "",
            "endDate": "",
            "serviceCategoryFeaturs": null
        },
        "payInfo": {
            "isPaied": false,
            "paymentAmount": 90000.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get a response body from example with Postman? If yes, please add a sample response to your question.

Comment: Here You go my friend!

Comment: You are trying to create your model from `response.body`, but actual data is inside the body, you have to use `response.body["data"]` to get it.

Comment: Can you specify where I should use that? I think I have used it already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out! My main mistake was in the mapping function in the `ServiceModel`.

The `response` was fine. The `response.body` had data and the `Json.decode(response.body)` returned a reasonable value and then the `snapchat` was **NULL**.

The only thing that remained uncheck between `Json.decode` and `snapchat` was `ServiceModel.fromJson((json.decode(response.body)))`.

By removing every field of the ServiceModel, Data, ServiceInfo, PayInfo in turn; I managed to find the problem.
It was because I had defined a `description` field and forgot to define it in my `fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` as well. So this little problem made the mapping go wrong because it was defined but it wasn't getting any value and it returned null.

On the other hand it seemed flutter decided to return null as the whole answer than just the suspicious field!

Answer (score 0):

So, when we are looking for data on the internet (fetching data) we have to use **asynchronous (await and async) technique** to avoid any issues because the data takes some time to get ready to show on our widget or to use it.

**In your case:** You text the snapshot and:

- If it has data it will show on the UI.
- If it doesn't you will see the **loading indicator and that's the issue!**

You have to make a return statement that will return the loading indicator while the data is loading.

For more information read this useful [documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) and this [model](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/).

P.S: This code was written without the editor so you might find some errors.

```
FutureBuilder<ServiceModel>(
        future: _service.getServiceDetail(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print('snapshot error');
            
          } 
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                child: (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                    ? Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: parseColor("F8A387"),
                          ),
                        ))
                    : DetailedServicePager(data: snapshot.data!));
          }
          return Center(
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            );
        },
      )
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer my friend  but it still doesn't work. the console prints `snapshot error` but I can't find the root of error and as for await&async technique  you mentioned ,I think I used it in my `getServiceDetail()` function.